# ASP.NET MVC: Disable Submit button if Client Validation passes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple MVC4 form with **Client Validation** enabled:

```
 @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
 @{ Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(); }
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmMain" }))
    {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken() .....
      <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSubmit" />
```

When the user clicks the submit **and all validation passes on the client**, I wish to have the submit button disabled as per jQuery below. How do I know if the validation has passed client side in side my jQuery script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $(this).attr('value', 'Working');
        $('#frmMain').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can hook this code into the form validator. Just make sure it executes AFTER the jquery.validator.unobtrusive.

```
<script>
    $("#you-form-id").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function(form) {
         $("#submit-button").attr("disabled",true).val("Working");
         form.submit();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is this safer than simple wrapping the function in something like:  if ($('#frmMain').valid()) {

Comment: I supposed both ways work, and there's no right answer when you're using jQuery Validator plugin. With the submitHandler (despite the code being uglier) you're only processing the validation once and I'm not entirelly sure if calling valid() would re-validate all the fields, something that can have some marginal performance impact.

Answer (score 13):

I had some issues when return a partail from the controller action. Instead I hooked in to the submit function and checked that the form was valid like this:

```
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $('#order-form-submit-button').attr("disabled", true).val("wait...");
            }
        });
```